# Will the resources allocated to OpenVZ containers be freed after i stop it?

Tags: openvz

we have many containers in a proxmox OpenVZ host and each of them have resources allocated to it (CPU, Memory, etc..)

if i `vzctl stop <CTID>` a container, will the allocated resources be free out? or it will still be in use?

i've recently stopped quite a few containers but didnt pay attention to the free memory and CPU usage but they seems like didn't drop much. i wonder if the containers that i stopped but not deleted are still holding the resources i allocated to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a container is stopped, then it has no processes running.  Therefore, a stopped container cannot possibly be consuming CPU or memory.

That said, even a stopped container can have its filesystem mounted or unmounted — perhaps you consider having the filesystem mounted "using a resource".